# Vocal/ Humming troubles

Tags: exercises, voice-training, vocal-cords

I am recovering from a sinus issue. Much has improved except for whatever muscle it takes to hum. I do the puppy whining exercises and can't get it to work. Therefore I have no midrange. I've steamed my voice/head, drank fluids 24/7, neti-potted, facial stretches, antibiotics and prednisone shot. 
    My question is what muscle is not working? swollen or otherwise? I can tell if I'm going to sing well if my humming exercises go well and they are NOT! Help! I have a 4 hour gig in two days and I'm frantic.
    Suggestions? Do I not do exercises or do them? 
Thanks!
Cindi

Comment: You may want to call in a sub

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right there in your first sentence... *"recovering"*.
Once you've actually *recovered*, you'll be fine.

No good trying to rush it & push it, you'll hurt something if you're not careful.

Cancel the gig.

Answer (score 1):

Your vocal fold tissues are still inflamed from your sinus issues.
 **The main muscles involved in phonation are the vocalis, the crico-thyroid, and the thyro-arytenoid.** 
In a recovering/inflammation situation, the mid-range is the last to come back. Cancel the gig, hire a sub, but don't try to sing a 4-hour gig in two days. That will just make it worse. Allow yourself time to recover.
**The quickest way is complete vocal rest.**